Do Postgres timestamp indexes work with greater than or less than operators?
I have a Postgres table with an 'at' timestamp column:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."Impressions"
(
    _id character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    at timestamp with time zone,
    CONSTRAINT "Impressions_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (_id)
)

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS at_idx
    ON public."Impressions" USING btree
    (at ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

When I do an explain plan on this query I would expect it to do an index scan with the at_idx index, but it doesn't seem to.
Select * from public."Impressions" I where I."at" >= '2024-01-01'
Seq Scan on Impressions as i
Filter: (at >= '2024-01-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone)

But if I just query on equal, it does use the index.
Select * from public."Impressions" I where I."at" = '2024-01-01'
Index Scan using at_idx on Impressions as i
Index Cond: (at = '2024-01-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone)

From my research, btree indexes are supposed to allow greater than and less then operators, right? Is there something else I'm missing?

Yes it does, see the index operators: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html#INDEXES-TYPES-BTREE That the index is not used in your query, depends on your data and the configuration of your database. You can read more about the query planner in this chapter: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-stats-details.html

Without the EXPLAIN ANALYZE output of the queries this is not answerable. Though as a general rule if enough rows meet the criteria a sequence scan becomes more efficient then using an index scan as using an index involves doing a lookup.
